# Xamarin Forms connect microphone to retrieve data for translator speech api from Azure

Tags: android, iphone, azure, xamarin.forms, microphone

How can I connect to the mic of my device (Android or Iphone) using Xamarin Forms and retrive the data in real time? this is for Microsoft Translator Speech API from Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to: [Xamarin: Speech Recognition Using the Microsoft Speech API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/cognitive-services/speech-recognition)

> The Microsoft Speech API is a cloud-based API that provides algorithms to process spoken language. This article explains how to use the Microsoft Speech Recognition REST API to convert audio to text in a Xamarin.Forms application.